# workflow to keep record of a previous balance of a balance and add a project budget to that person once the project is acepted

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

How i create a workflow to keep record of a previous balance of a person's balance and add a project budget to that person's balance once the project is accepted.Also their balance can't exceed a $50000 per year.

Thanks.